# nginx does not starting with multiple nodejs apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy

i have this config in sites-enabled/default

```
upstream domainone.com.ar {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
listen   80;
server_name  www.domainone.com.ar;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://domainone.com.ar/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name domainone.com.ar;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/example1.com/access.log;
    location / {
      if ($request_uri ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$) {
          expires 168h; 
          break;
      }
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://domainone.com.ar;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}


upstream domaintwo.com.ar {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
listen   80;
server_name  domaintwo.com.ar;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://domaintwo.com.ar/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.domaintwo.com.ar;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/example1.com/access.log;
    location / {
      if ($request_uri ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$) {
          expires 168h; 
          break;
      }
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://domaintwo.com.ar;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

when i try to /etc/init.d/nginx start... nothing happends... no error no log no nothing...
my server is a cloud server debian 6, 64bits nodejs v0.10 nginx 1.2.6
there is something wrong with config??

Comment: it should tell you if your config was false... Maybe you should consider saving your config file and reinstall nginx